# Page doesn't re-render when react context variable changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-context

I am using React context to keep a global theme state.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react"

const ThemeContext = createContext(localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light")

export const ThemeStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light")

  const handleThemeChange = theme => {
    setTheme(theme)
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light")
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, changeTheme: handleThemeChange }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ThemeContext
```

I am providing this context in my Layout Component so that my entire app can access the store. Below is my Layout component.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import Header from "./header"
import "../styles/layout.css"
import ThemeContext, { ThemeStore } from "../contexts/ThemeContext"
import MobileBottomNav from "../components/mobileBottomNav"

// Wrapper for background color
const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)

  return (
    <div className={`${theme.theme === "dark" ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"}`}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const Layout = ({ children, hideHeader, hideFooterNavBar }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeStore>
      <Wrapper>
        <div className="bg-bg-primary">
          <Header hideHeader={hideHeader} />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <MobileBottomNav hideFooterNavBar={hideFooterNavBar} />
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    </ThemeStore>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

I have a button in my Header component that changes the theme from light to dark and vice versa. And my menu component etc. all change their colors, as I've added conditional classnames.

But in my signin page, which is also wrapped around the  provider doesn't update when the state is changed. So if I change the theme from dark to light but it doesn't re-render the signup page, and hence the colors don't change. Why is it so? How do I make the page re-render when the theme changes so the new colors are applied.

Here is my signin page.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"

import SEO from "../components/seo"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import ThemeContext from "../contexts/ThemeContext"

const SignInPage = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)

  // This just logs the initial value of theme, but when I change 
  // the theme from the header component, this value doesn't log again. 
  // The component doesn't re-render.
  console.log(theme)

  return (
    <Layout hideFooterNavBar={true}>
      <SEO title="Sign In" />
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            paddingTop: "150px",
          }}
          className="container mx-auto"
        >
          <p
            className={`${
              theme.theme === "dark" ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"
            } text-text-primary mb-10`}
          >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non
            sapien blandit, aliquet lorem quis, consectetur tellus. Maecenas ac
            nibh eu enim auctor volutpat. Mauris a lacus magna. Proin
            sollicitudin mauris sit amet auctor feugiat. Nulla facilisi.
            Pellentesque eget massa nec massa porta tristique in vitae ante.
            Donec rutrum imperdiet urna.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default SignInPage
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary from the code samples you posted. Are you sure you only have 1 `ThemeContext.Provider`, and that `SignupPage` is a child of that `ThemeContext.Provider`? 

I would recommend installing the React Devtools chrome extension so you can inspect your components, and see the value of context providers.

Comment: Not just the signup page but also the Index Page. Both are wrapped with the <Layout> component and the Layout component is wrapped by the <ThemeStore> component which has the provider. Yet it doesn't re-render.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the devtools.
https://imgur.com/a/59PSDdJ

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are consuming `ThemeContext` beneath where you're providing a value to `ThemeContext.Provider`.

If you check the React devtools you should see that your tree looks something like this:

- SignInPage

  - Layout

    - ThemeStore
    - ThemeContext.Provider

      - Wrapper

What you can do instead is consume the context in a component that is a child of `Layout` or use a higher order component to inject the ThemeContext into `SignInPage`:

```
const SignInPage = ({ theme }) => {
  // ...
}

export default props => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {theme => 
      <SignInPage theme={theme} {...props} />
    }
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
)
```

Comment: ```
export default props => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {theme => 
      <SignInPage theme={theme} {...props} />
    }
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
)
```
Didn't work. If wrapper and all it's children are children of ThemeContext.Provider then shouldn't all the components under it automatically re-render when the provider value changes?

Comment: @RahulSharma `SignInPage` is not a child of `Wrapper` though; I pointed this out at the top. If the wrapper didn't work, what did happen? What data was passed to `SignInPage` as the `theme` prop?

Comment: @RahulSharma Do you still need help with this? Did this answer your question?